# Laravel multiple columns for whereIn with subquery

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

In MySQL, to search multiple columns in a "WHERE IN" clause it is normally done as:

```
where (column1, column2) in (select column1, column2 from table)
```

I am trying to achieve the same result as this in Laravel and tried doing something like:

```
->whereIn(['column1', 'column2'], function($query){
            $query->select('column1', 'column2')
            ->from('table');
        })
```

How could I do the same thing as I have done with MySQL, on Laravel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve that using `DB::raw` like so:

```
->whereIn(DB::raw('(`column1`, `column2`)'), function($query){
        $query->select('column1', 'column2')
        ->from('table');
    })
```

Comment: what should i do if i have array like this 
[[3, 1], [6, 1], [5, 1]] instead of getting columns values fr table